# Is Java method with a single argument to receive values of both HashMap<String, Integer> and HashMap<Long, Integer> possible?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to create a method that will sort a HashMap by keys. The HashMap's keys can be String or Long. The processing of the two HashMap types is similar. In order to avoid code duplication I want to create a single method to handle both cases.

The method's code:

```
static LinkedHashMap<Long, Integer> sortNumberHashMapByKey(HashMap<Long, Integer> map){
        ArrayList<Long> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(keys);
        Collections.sort(values);
        LinkedHashMap<Long, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Integer value : values) {
            Iterator<Long> keyIt = keys.iterator();
            while (keyIt.hasNext()){
                Long key = keyIt.next();
                if (map.get(key).equals(value)){
                    keyIt.remove();
                    sortedMap.put(key, value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }
```

Is it possible to create a Java method with a single argument that can receive values of both `HashMap<String, Integer>` and `HashMap<Long, Integer>` types?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Generics`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a `T` which needs to implement `Comparable<T>` and then replace any usage of `Long` with `T`:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> LinkedHashMap<T, Integer> sortNumberHashMapByKey(HashMap<T, Integer> map){
    ArrayList<T> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    Collections.sort(keys);
    Collections.sort(values);
    LinkedHashMap<T, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (Integer value : values) {
        Iterator<T> keyIt = keys.iterator();
        while (keyIt.hasNext()){
            T key = keyIt.next();
            if (map.get(key).equals(value)){
                keyIt.remove();
                sortedMap.put(key, value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Generics` in java to define a method that works on a particular type e.i. in your case Sting and Long(both are of Comparable) The code will then look like:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> LinkedHashMap<E, Integer> sortNumberHashMapByKey(HashMap<E, Integer> map){
    ArrayList<E> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    Collections.sort(keys);
    Collections.sort(values);
    LinkedHashMap<E, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (Integer value : values) {
        Iterator<E> keyIt = keys.iterator();
        while (keyIt.hasNext()){
            E key = keyIt.next();
            if (map.get(key).equals(value)){
                keyIt.remove();
                sortedMap.put(key, value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Here `<E extends Comparable<E>>` is the type that you would like to pass to your method. And then use this type `E` in your code to do the operations that are common to both `String` and `Long`.